# Describe result set in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql-server, postgresql

In Microsoft Sql Server, there is a proc `sys.sp_describe_first_result_set` which takes an arbitrary sql query string and returns data describing the types that would be in the result set, were it to be executed. Note, this is describing the results of a complex query, not a table. [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878602.aspx)

Is there anything similar for Postgres?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [at the protocol level](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/protocol.html) - in the form of the [Describe](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/protocol-message-formats.html) message in the [extended query protocol](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/protocol-flow.html#PROTOCOL-FLOW-EXT-QUERY).

I'm not aware of any SQL-level equivalent for arbitrary SQL strings. Good idea though; raise it on pgsql-general . I suspect it'd be pretty easy to implement.

In fact, a quick look at `exec_describe_statement_message` in `src/backend/tcop/postgres.c` shows that the brains are in `SendRowDescriptionMessage` in `src/backend/access/common/printtup.c`. It shouldn't be hard to write a simple C extension to do similar work and produce a resultset. Hopefully a couple of hours work if you're familar with the codebase; the idea would be:

- Feed the SQL string into the parser/rewriter/planner to obtain a plan
- Find the targetlist of the top level node, if any. This will be the `RETURNING` node for DML, or the top-level `Query` tlist for a `SELECT`.
- Feed the tlist into `ExecTypeFromTL`
- Loop over the tupledesc entries, skipping `resjunk` columns by looking them up in the tlist, and emit a row for each non-resjunk output from the query.

Comment: There might be a (semantic) problem with domains and UDTs. Though the type can be reported, the frontend might not be able to make eany sense of this output.

Comment: @joop Good thought. There's not much that can be done about that, except teaching the client to query the catalogs to learn about the types/domains. After all it's no different to built-in non-SQL-standard types like `json`. For domains, we can also optionally resolve them to their underlying types, but that might be misleading in other ways.

Comment: @joop In the end, if the client is using those types, they're expected to know what they mean. If they're accepting arbitrary queries they'll have to know how to query the `information_schema` or system catalogs.

Comment: @CraigRinger: that's where the semantics kick in. For instance: GIS-extentions will always have a textual represntation, but the client will need to parse and process this. So in effect, the `DESCRIBE` is only useful in trivial cases. Finally: knowing that a column (expression) in the query result has type `integer NOT NULL` and name `q1_barbie_score_with_voodoo_correction` will stil not help the frontend.

Comment: @wildplasser Actually, it's not necessarily true that PostGIS `geometry` or `geography` types will be sent in textual form. They may be sent in binary form if that's requested by the client. But of course, the client will then know that.

Comment: I know. It was just to illustrate that the knowledge of the `technical` type is insufficient. The client needs to know the semantics. (this is what I use to call `the XML trap` ;-)

Comment: The intended use for this was to generate types for result sets at compile time, in an F# type provider. Simple types would be ok, but I am in no position to contribute to Postgres. :/

Answer (score 2):

I tried to do this by creating a stored procedure to create `temperory view` then check information_schema.columns before droping the view.

Comment: That's actually quite genius!

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a little [extension for PostgreSQL](https://github.com/nick-ivanov-edb/pg_describe_resultset) that returns the basic information about columns of a result set.

After installing it, execute `SELECT * FROM describe_resultset('<your query>')`,
and you'll get something like this:

```
 column_name | column_type | column_type_name | column_len | column_attrs
-------------+-------------+------------------+------------+--------------
 foo         |          23 | int4             |          4 |
 bar         |        1700 | numeric          |         -1 |
(2 rows)
```

It uses [`SPI_prepare()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/spi-spi-prepare.html) to parse the statement and obtain the necessary information.