# Retrieve query metadata in Postgres

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

With a C# .net application connecting to postgres using npgsql, how do I recover the just the metadata of a sql query? Is their any equivalent to the Transact SQL option FMTONLY, where the request returns no rows, and makes no changes, but populates the column meta-data with the schema information - column names and data types?

Comment: [Describe result set in PostgreSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25899722/describe-result-set-in-postgresql)

Comment: Reading that link, if I understand well, this Describe message exists in a low level protocol but is not directly usable from npgsql?

Comment: How about `LIMIT 0`?